# how to redirect to another post without getting headers already sent error?

Tags: plugin-development

Normally the code below works for my purpose.
I need to check if a post is in a certain category, check against user role and only allow user to see the page if the roles match

```
function bbrew_check_wholesaler(){
    if( is_user_logged_in() ){

        if(!check_is_role('myrole'){
            wp_redirect($page_to_redirct_to);
            exit;
        }
    }
    else{
            wp_redirect($page_to_redirct_to);
            exit;
    }
}
```

The helper function is

```
function check_is_role($role){
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    $user_roles = $current_user->roles;
    $user_role = $user_roles[0];
    if($user_role == $role){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
    die;
}
```

Both the wp_loaded and init hooks do not have the global $post loaded either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are in the front end, you can use [`template_redirect`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/template_redirect) hook to achieve what you want:

```
function bbrew_check_wholesaler() {

    global $post;

    /**
     * If we are viewing a single post page that has the specified category "foobar"
     * and the user does not have the specified role "myrole" then redirect the user
     * away from this page.
     */
    if ( is_single() && has_category('foobar', $post) && ! check_is_role('myrole') ) {
        wp_safe_redirect(home_url('away-from-post'));
        exit;
    }

}

add_action( 'template_redirect', 'bbrew_check_wholesaler' );
```

Note: in the above example we can forgoe the use of `is_user_logged_in()` as the subsequent call to `wp_get_current_user()` will return an empty `WP_User` object if the user is logged out.

I would adjust your `check_is_role()` function to the following:

```
function check_is_role($role){

    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();

    if ( in_array($role, $current_user->roles ) 
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }

}
```

...as the specified role you are checking for could exist anywhere within the array return on the `roles` property and only at index 0.

You can further extend the above callback function with,

- [`has_category()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_category)
- [`has_tag()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_tag)
- [`has_term()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_term)

...in order to determine whether the post object has the specified term or terms required.

Comment: Thank you for doing a bit of housekeeping as well, appreciate it

Comment: @Digamber No problem...